# ¿Cómo importar módulos correctamente?

Tags: python, clase, herencia, pygame, modulos

Tengo un proyecto que tiene los siguientes directorios: está la carpeta en donde está el main.py y la carpeta Game. En la carpeta Game esta settings.py la cual quiero utilizar la clase basicConfig del codigo settings.py

Y me sale que no está definido. Código:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from Game.settings import BasicConfig


 pygame.init()



def Main():
    while Settings.running:
          print("miau")
          Settings.clock.tick(30)
          pygame.quit()
Main()
```

Y este es el módulo. No sé cómo se llame osea el código que deseo utilizar

```
  class BasicConfig:
        def __init__(self):
             self.WindowWidth = 900
             self.WindowHeight = 500
             self.CoordinateY = 0
             self.CoordinateX = 0
             self.ZoomWidth = 0
             self.ZoomHeight = 0
             self.p1 = 0
             self.p2 = 0
             self.running = True
             self.Font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)


    class HighConf(BasicConfig):
          def __init__(self):
               self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
               super().__init__()
               self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WindowWidth, self.WindowHeight))



      def HConfig(self):
           self.screen.fill(azul)
           pygame.display.flip()



      def EventLoop(self):
          while self.running:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                       self.running = False
                       pygame.quit()
```

Y me sale un error :

> NameError: name 'Settings' is not defined

Comment: ahhhh me olvide decir que el codigo settings.py  esta en otra carpeta llamada game todo el codigo seria algo asi juego/main.py/game/settings.py

Comment: Supongo que en tu función `Main()` deberías haber escrito `while BasicConfig.running:` en vez de `Settings.running`

Comment: En tu función Main `Settings` se toma como variable y nunca la haz definido, si lo requieres de *pygame*  haz la importación necesaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicación**:

`NameError: name 'Settings' is not defined` te indica que estás usando `Settings` y no lo has definido.

Fíjate en que estás importando `settings`, no `Settings`.

**Solución**:

En vez de escribir

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from Game.settings import BasicConfig
```

Prueba escribiendo lo siguiente (y renombrar settings.py a Settings.py)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import Game.Settings
```